# Contact form: determine which submit button was used

Tags: contacts, extension

As in my previous question, I've added (through an extension) a new Submit button "Save and add Contribution" to the Contact form.
Now, in postProces hook, when this button has been pressed, I want to redirect to the "new contribution" form.
At the moment I can not understand which submit button was pressed.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I think this provides a pretty decent answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680160/how-can-i-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-a-php-form-submit

Comment: How do you create a button. Can you post some code ?